# "Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)" Error from Anchor Test

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

[image]

My tests all run successfully, but at the end of my test execution, I get error `Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)`.

On the anchor discord, I found a thread from February detailing the same issue I had [discord link](https://discord.com/channels/889577356681945098/889702325231427584/939661292795494480).
I recently also added another program to my anchor project, similar to the user who posted on discord, but I only saw this error after upgrading to anchor `anchor-cli 0.25.0` and solana `solana-cli 1.10.32`.

My `Anchor.toml` has the following. I get the error both in CI and locally, and both environments have ts-mocha and yarn installed.

```
[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 --parallel"
```

Edit: Looks like it might be a race condition?
Removing the `parallel` flag I now get the below. So I still get the error, but it happens before the success.

```
Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
✨  Done in 432.44s.
```

Edit: Looks like the issue is with multi-programs, or at least the way I have them setup. Removing `whirlpool` from the directory structure removes the issue.
[image]

Edit: Fixed!!!
I needed this in my dummy whirlpool program

```
#[program]
pub mod whirlpool {
    use super::*;

    // _val to ensure tx are different so they don't get rejected.
    pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>, _val: u64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}
```

Comment: For me the fix was to install the latest version of Solana Tool Suite: https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Answer (score 3):

For multi-program projects, if one of them is a `dummy` program, you need something like this. The reason is anchor is likely looking for the `idl` file for this program and it doesn't get generated if there is no program.

```
#[program]
pub mod whirlpool {
    use super::*;

    // _val to ensure tx are different so they don't get rejected.
    pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>, _val: u64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}
```

Comment: Thank you! You can also simplify this by not using any instructions `#[program] pub mod my_program {}`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, `Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)`. In my case `yarn` and `node` where missing, I forgot to install them.

- `npm install --global yarn`
- `sudo apt install nodejs`